nodetool status shows unwanted nodes, non-Cassandra nodes, unreal DC
While trying to do a rolling upgrade on a 6 nodes Cluster (DC1), the nodetool status started to show unwanted UN nodes (cassandra) from another DC (DC2) and unwanted DN nodes (non cassandra) from a 3rd DC (DC3)
DC3 looks like not real DC because its nodes are not Cassandra nodes.
DC1 and DC2 were well deployed at first, and already used to save data without issues while doing nodetool status.
I use 3 seed nodes (odd ones) to setup the 6 nodes, and these seed nodes are not the same for DC1 and DC2.
The only problem I see now is that DC1 and DC2 have the same cluster_name and I am thinking that this is the root cause of my issue.
My questions are:

How could DC2 join DC1? How can I reproduce it in development? because I tried similar scenario, 2 clusters with same cluster_name, but the issue is not happening.
Why I see extra non-cassandra nodes from unreal DC?
Why the problem did not show-up at first but only now ?
What is the best way to fix this? One solution I found is here: cassandra - Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name

Actual
# nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
=========================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  IP_1_DC_1  4.87 GiB   256          ?       aaaaaaaa-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
UN  IP_2_DC_1  6.66 GiB   256          ?       bbbbbbbb-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3
UN  IP_3_DC_1  5.28 GiB   256          ?       cccccccc-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
UN  IP_4_DC_1  9.55 GiB   256          ?       dddddddd-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
UN  IP_5_DC_1  6.32 GiB   256          ?       eeeeeeee-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
UN  IP_6_DC_1  6.47 GiB   256          ?       ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3
Datacenter: DC3
=========================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  IP_1_DC_3   11.99 GiB  256          ?       gggggggg-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3
DN  IP_2_DC_3   12.66 GiB  256          ?       hhhhhhhh-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
DN  IP_3_DC_3   12.57 GiB  256          ?       iiiiiiii-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
DN  IP_4_DC_3   12.63 GiB  256          ?       jjjjjjjj-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
DN  IP_5_DC_3   13.1 GiB   256          ?       kkkkkkkk-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3
Datacenter: DC2
=========================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  IP_1_DC_2   14.92 GiB  256          ?       llllllll-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
UN  IP_2_DC_2   9.08 GiB   256          ?       mmmmmmmm-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
UN  IP_3_DC_2   8.8 GiB    256          ?       nnnnnnnn-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
UN  IP_4_DC_2   10.26 GiB  256          ?       oooooooo-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3
UN  IP_5_DC_2   9.59 GiB   256          ?       pppppppp-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
UN  IP_6_DC_2   10.75 GiB  256          ?       qqqqqqqq-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless

# nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
    Name: DSE-Cassandra-same-name
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        aaaaaaaa-cccc-cccc-cccc-bbbbbbbbbbbb: [IP_1_DC_1, IP_2_DC_1, IP_3_DC_1, IP_4_DC_1, IP_5_DC_1, IP_6_DC_1, IP_1_DC_2, IP_2_DC_2, IP_3_DC_2, IP_4_DC_2, IP_5_DC_2, IP_6_DC_2]

        UNREACHABLE: [IP_1_DC_3, IP_2_DC_3, IP_3_DC_3, IP_4_DC_3, IP_5_DC_3]

Expected
# nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
=========================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  IP_1_DC_1  4.87 GiB   256          ?       aaaaaaaa-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
UN  IP_2_DC_1  6.66 GiB   256          ?       bbbbbbbb-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3
UN  IP_3_DC_1  5.28 GiB   256          ?       cccccccc-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
UN  IP_4_DC_1  9.55 GiB   256          ?       dddddddd-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC2
UN  IP_5_DC_1  6.32 GiB   256          ?       eeeeeeee-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC1
UN  IP_6_DC_1  6.47 GiB   256          ?       ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-gggggggggggg  RAC3


Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Before answering your questions, I'll start by briefly clarifying some of the core Cassandra concepts that you mentioned.

Cassandra cluster - A group of one or more datacenters
Cassandra datacenter - A logical group of one or more nodes, typically closely tied to keyspace replication (with NetworkTopologyStrategy)

From the output of nodetool status you have a single cluster - this means that all of the nodes there were bootstrapped with the value DSE-Cassandra-same-name in cluster_name, and at least 1 live node from this cluster in their seed list in cassandra.yaml.
This cluster currently contains 3 datacenters with 5-6 nodes each.
The fact that you have 3 datacenters means that each set of datacenter nodes was started with cassandra-rackdc.properties with the respective values for dc (DC1, DC2 or DC3 in this case).

DC3 looks like not real DC because its nodes are not Cassandra nodes

Can you specify what you mean by "not Cassandra nodes"? These nodes may perhaps no longer exist, since currently they are marked as DN (Down and Normal), but at some point they were definitely Cassandra nodes and part of this cluster.
Either way, if you want to remove the DC3 from the cluster, you should be able to by running on any live node nodetool removenode <node_id> where node_id is the id of each of DC3 nodes. I would also check every keyspace replication, and remove DC3 from it, if applicable.

I use 3 seed nodes (odd ones) to setup the 6 nodes, and these seed nodes are not the same for DC1 and DC2.

Since DC1 and DC2 are part of the same cluster, it's highly recommended that all nodes in all datacenters are configured with the same seed list. Typically, 3 seeds per datacenter (1 per rack ideally) is enough.

The only problem I see now is that DC1 and DC2 have the same cluster_name and I am thinking that this is the root cause of my issue.

If you'd like to have DC1 and DC2 in 2 separate clusters, you are right in this assessment.

How could DC2 join DC1? How can I reproduce it in development? because I tried similar scenario, 2 clusters with same cluster_name, but the issue is not happening.

Not sure this answers your question, but can't merge datacenters in Cassandra, since you can't change the topology of nodes once they join the ring. Furthermore, if this was possible, it would seriously mess up data replication for any keyspace using NetworkTopologyStrategy. If all your keyspaces are using SimpleStrategy, however, DC1 and DC2 nodes are effectively acting as a part of a single datacenter and rack.
My guess is that in the scenario you tried to replicate in development you didn't get the two datacenters in the same cluster because the seed lists were local nodes only. Seeds act as a first point of contact when a node joins the cluster to get ring metadata, schema, etc. If you create two datacenters with the same cluster_name but they don't have at least a seed node from the other datacenter, you'll end up with 2 single-datacenter clusters instead of a single 2-datacenter cluster.

Why I see extra non-cassandra nodes from unreal DC?

More context above, but I think these nodes at some became part of the cluster due to the cluster name matching, and seeds acting as a point of contact.

Why the problem did not show-up at first but only now?

It depends on what the problem is exactly. If you mean that you should only be seeing DC1 in the nodetool status output, then my guess is that nodes from DC1 somehow got into the seed list of nodes in other datacenters or vice-versa, making so that nodes contacted each other.

What is the best way to fix this? One solution I found is here: cassandra - Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name

I tested the linked solution and I don't think it will work. If your goal is to allocate each datacenter DC1 and DC2 in a separate cluster, I would recommend:

Creating a new cluster to allocate one of the datacenters
Replicate the schema definition in the new cluster
Migrate the data to the new datacenter. There are several tools that can help you with this - sstableloader, dsbulk, cqlsh COPY, DataStax Spark migrator, zero downtime proxy
Decommission the migrated datacenter in the original cluster after the migration is over.


Thanks @mário-tavares for your time , very appreciated. And very interesting response, I will verify your different theories ASAP.

These three things are required for nodes to form a cluster:

cluster_name,
shared seed(s), and
network connectivity.

If any of these are missing, the nodes will not join together as a Cassandra cluster.
In your situation where you didn't want DC2 to be part of the DC1 cluster, you should't have (a) used the same cluster_name OR (b) shared seeds between the nodes. Had those nodes (c) been in different networks with no connectivity between them then it wouldn't have been a problem if (a) or (b) were true since they wouldn't be able to form a cluster.
Now you say that nodes in DC3 are not Cassandra nodes. My suspicion is (d) they are running Cassandra but you just don't know about it, OR (e) they used to be C* nodes but they've been re-purposed. If (e) is true then it's likely that (f) some of the nodes (whether in DC1 or DC2) already had the DC3 nodes listed as peers when you re-purposed the nodes without decommissioning them correctly.
If you are playing around with the nodes and re-provisioning them withOUT wiping their data (data/, commitlog/, saved_caches/, etc) then the information that is persisted in the tables will get resurrected.
Best practice is to always go through a decommissioning process that includes wiping all configuration and data to avoid running in this situation. This is particularly important when working in production environments because of the impact it could have when nodes inadvertently join production clusters. Cheers!
